# MS Excel cell references shifting after using a macro?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, macros

Basically this is what happens:
On Sheet1 I have a column of cells that are linked to other cells on sheet2. Looks something like this.

Sheet1!A1=Sheet2!A1

Sheet1!A2=Sheet2!A2

Sheet1!A3=Sheet2!A3 etc.

Then I use a macro that does some filtering and such and when I then look at the aforementioned cells on Sheet1 they look like this.

Sheet1!A1=Sheet2!#REF!

Sheet1!A2=Sheet2!A1

Sheet1!A3=Sheet2!A2

When I use the macro again, the references shift again.

Sheet1!A1=Sheet2!#REF!

Sheet1!A2=Sheet2!#REF!

Sheet1!A3=Sheet2!A1

I can't for the life of me figure out what's causing it. What especially boggles my mind is that the macro I use does not do ANYTHING on Sheet1. It does change the cells on Sheet2 that the cells on Sheet1 are linked to, but other than that it does nothing on Sheet1.

It basically just filters data on Sheet3, pasts the filtered stuff on Sheet2 and then it removes duplicate values. That's literally all it does. Could someone explain this to me please? Thanks.

Comment: I'm having a hard time decrypting your notation. Could you please explicitly describe what you expect, and what's going wrong?

Comment: Also, take a look at the formatting help and see if you can use those to clarify the notation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is since you're deleting everything on Sheet 2, it looses the reference and once a formula goes to that #REF! error it doesn't go back until you change it.  The only thing I can think of without having more information on what you're really trying to do, would be to let the macro reset the references on Sheet1 when it's done.

Note to mod: I would comment but don't have enough rep yet.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was thinking about it at work today and figured out what was causing it. The macro was removing the first row on Sheet2 (>removing< not just deleting data) and this somehow caused the  references on Sheet1 to shift. I rewrote it so that it doesn't need to delete the first row anymore and all is well. Thanks again though, having the macro reset the references is something I didn't think off and it would probably solve the problem too :)